# How to delete folder along with the files from database also?

Tags: 7, database, files

I want to delete selected folder along with all files inside that folder. I tried by using `file_unmanaged_delete_recursive()` It will delete folders and files but it is not removing database entry of files and not even it is making the Status of the file to Zero. So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

[`file_unmanaged_delete_recursive()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_unmanaged_delete_recursive/7.x), as the name implies, removes any files under a directory without concern to managed files (i.e. files tracked in the database).

In order to remove files from the database, you can make use of the [`file_delete()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_delete/7.x) function in the [File API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/group/file/7.x). This function needs the file ID supplied as an argument, so you'll need to perform a query on the database to retrieve it. For example:

```
$files = file_scan_directory('sites/default/files/my_custom_dir', '/.*/', array('recurse' => TRUE));
foreach($files as $file) { 
  $scanned_file_uri = file_build_uri($file->uri); 
  // @TODO: query file_managed.uri for match with $scanned_file_uri
  // then delete with file_delete();
}
```